# hide cgi command window on windows php task schedule

Tags: php, cgi, scheduled-tasks

I was trying to set a windows task schedule for a php file and done that successfully.
The problem is "**C:\xampp\php\php.exe**" that is the cgi exe for older versions of php5. But for newer versions it should be "**C:\xampp\php\php-cgi.exe**" and now my whole packet looks like this:

**C:\xampp\php\php-cgi.exe -f "C:\xampp\htdocs....\file.php"**

so building on that my questions are:

1. when the script is running there the command window of the cgi exe always appears and disappears after half second or sth like. Is there a way to hide or disable the window?
2. I read sth. about the **php-win.exe**. The source described it as without window appearing. So I tried it but the script do not run with the  **C:\xampp\php\php-win.exe**.

Do you guys know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

Put your `php script.php` call in the .bat file, and then add this to the task:

```
CMD /C START /MIN your.bat
```

or you can run .bat file with other user (other than yourself)...

Comment: thanks but i dont know anything about .bat files. could you give me a short example or do you know any ressources with good examples? hard to filter the search in exactly this theme.... thanks.

Comment: Open notepad and write your execute code in there, and save file as something.bat. If you double click the fill, the commands you wrote should run...

Comment: tried it out now... script is working but console windows is appearing again.... any options to set ?